# Is it possible to start glDrawElementsInstanced from a certain instance (with a certain offset in a buffer containing per instance attributes)

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering

I would like to draw similar instances (leaves) containing in different meshes (trees) (with different MVP matrices). I draw leaves using glDrawElementsInstanced where MVP matrices of leaves (in coordinates of a tree) are kept in a separate buffer. This MVP matrix goes into an input variable of the vertex per every instance (marked as instance data). But I cannot find a way to render leaves of a certain tree (to start drawing from a certain offset in MVP matrices buffer).

I searched google and found nothing in respect of that. Looks like the only way to render such instances - to have a separate buffer for every tree to keep per instance data.

But I would like to keep them in one buffer.

Is there any way to do it ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance.xhtml) is for. The offset is the last parameter.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this option is only available in OpenGL 4.2 and not available in OpenGL ES.